# weird behavior of UISlider

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uislider

I have an UISLider created programmatically inside UITableViewCell. the slider control works with audio file to show the progress .. this is the  creation:

```
    AudioSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78.0f, 28, 214, 10)];
    AudioSlider.maximumValue = 100.0;
    AudioSlider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    [AudioSlider setTag:5];
    [AudioSlider setValue:0.0];
    [[self contentView] addSubview:AudioSlider];
```

the problem is that the slider does not show the start and end values of the progress correctly !! when I set value to 0.0 :

```
[AudioSlider setValue:0.0];
[AudioSlider setValue:100.0];
```

the photo explain the problem
[image]

I can't really find out the reason ...

Any idea ?

thanks in advance ..

Comment: What you have shown in the screenshot is UIProgressView and NOT UISlider? Do you want to have a UIProgressView or UISlider?

Comment: Good spot, I missed that one :D

Comment: No .. it is UISlider .. but Im using transparent thumb image : [AudioSlider setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"trans.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have omitted some important code from your question.  It is clear from your screen shot that you have made the slider's thumb invisible, perhaps by using a transparent image.

Normally, the slider would cover those ends, so the user wouldn't see the wrongly-colored parts of the channel.  But by making the thumb invisible, you've made the ends visible.

If this is really supposed to be a slider that the user can interact with, you need to replace the minimum track image and maximum track image of the slider, or you need to use a thumb image that hides the ends.

If this isn't supposed to be a control that the user can interact with, use `UIProgressView` instead of `UISlider`.

Comment: rob.. thanks very much for saving my time .. the problem is : I'm using big transparent thumb image (200px width) !!! , just provide 1px width image and the problem solved ^_^ . By the way .. I'm actually using maximum track image and minimum track image, but disabled them during a large number of crazy test scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

It's in a tableView so I'd suggest that you're probably not setting it when you think you are due to cell dequeueing.

Can you show the code that creates and configures the UITableViewCells.